# restricting access to parts of website & server

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

On my website I am able to access my phpMyAdmin control panel by typing in the ip address followed by /phpmyadmin e.g.

`http://18.129.514.29/phpmyadmin/` (note: not my real ip)

I also need to limit access to SSH, currently all you need to do to get access to the server login screen is type the ip address of the server which anyone can get a hold of by pinging the server.

What measure can I take to make sure these issues do not become a security threat?

Answer (score 1):

Setting restrictions in your vhosts (can be done by adding an extra layer like http auth or by only allowing certain IP's).

Another option I would certainly advice to get is host based security like OSSEC. It automatically blocks most bruteforce attempts.

Also you can lower background noise by setting a non default ssh port.

Answer (score 1):

To control the access to the phpmyadmin, you can use some of the apache modules for access control (httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html) and Authentication and authorization httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html. The most common one is something [like this, using the IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714332/allow-request-coming-from-specific-ip-only) but you can use also usernames.

To control the access to you SSH, you can use iptables to restrict access and only allow certain IP's, or more interesting, use  BFD (www.rfxn.com/projects/brute-force-detection/)  (brute force detector), Denyhost denyhosts.sourceforge.net/  and Dos Deflate to avoid attacks. BFD, DDOS and Denyhost are simple scripts that check your logs for attacks, and ban the IP's of the attackers (Using iptables or APF), wich is very useful (it allows me to sleep well ;) and have almost no load on the server.
Here you have some [help installing](http://www.iplocation.net/tools/apf-bfd-ddos-rootkit.php) them

Comment: Sorry, but as a new user, i cant post more than 2 hyperlinks :S

Comment: looks interesting.